# Fast Fourier Transform With Microphone Input Data in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, function, audio

Is it possible to get the source of adobes `flash.media.SoundMixer` class ?

If it is, where can i find / get it ?

I waht to "clone" the `.computeSpectrum()` function to transform a raw sound wave ( byteArray ) from Microphone input into a frequency spectrum.

I've found a couple of examples like this one -> http://pierrickpluchon.fr/blog/as3-how-to-plug-your-microphone-with-a-soundspectrum-in-flash-player-10-1/

All other methos i've found are pretty much the same.

The problem is that there is always a `Sound()` playing, what i DON'T want. ( I don't want any loopback )

But if i'm not playing a sound, i can't use the `SoundMixer.computeSpectrum()` function to transform my ByteArray that comes from the `Microphone` to a frequency spectrum by turning the FFTMode to true ( `computeSpectrum(myByteArray,true)` )

Also if you know any other method to get the Frequency Spectrum from the Raw Sound Wave, please let me know.

**UPDATE**

my code:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.rate = 44;
// mic.gain = 100; // gain
mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);

function onSampleData( event:SampleDataEvent ):void {
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
    for( var i:uint = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
        var num:Number = event.data.readFloat() * 100 + 100; // -Math.abs( )
        if( i == 0 ) {
            graphics.moveTo( i, num );
        } else {
            graphics.lineTo( i, num );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> "..Also if you know any other method to get the Frequency Spectrum from the Raw Sound Wave, please let me know."

Well Joe Beuckman beat me to it and gave you the link to Gerry Beauregard's FFT code. That's the best AS3 one I've seen so far since I found it two years ago. From the comments I see you were wondering how to implement... Well to see implementation code you need to see another page on his blog:

http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/real-time-spectrum-analysis/

1. To test that code yourself you first have to save the classes shown in the link here: http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/an-even-faster-as3-fft/
   Save each package's code respectively as FFT2.as and FFTElement.as
2. Now in your document class put the code from:  http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/real-time-spectrum-analysis/

However in that code you must also add some lines importing the other saved .as classes

```
import __AS3__.vec.Vector;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.media.Microphone;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.*;

import FFT2;
import FFTElement;
```

Now it should run without errors and show the same thing as screenshot on his blog. The online demo used to work for me but not today so I say screenshot just so you know what to expect when it works fine.

Hope it helps. VC:One

Comment: PS: I have removed the bit about computeSpectrum as I've not had a chance to confirm on Flash what I wrote. I know it's possible to computeSpectrum on global sound with no input/output byteArray but I don't trust my memory whether it's as easy as what I originally wrote.

Answer (score 1):

FFT means the Fast Fourier Transform. That is exactly the algorithm that transforms the raw sound wave values into the frequency space. You should be able to find (or port) an implementation of the FFT in AS3, and that does what you ask.

Comment: do you have any reference for me ? i was not able to find anything that i understand how to implement...

Comment: I googled "fft as3" and the first link looks like it has usable source: http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/an-even-faster-as3-fft/

Comment: yes i also found this page the first. but i do not know how exactly i need to implement it. i'll update my code snipet in a minute. if you can tell me how to implement, i would be glad ^^

Comment: Without discussing Fourier math too too much, I think you would supply your audio data as "Real" values and give zeroes for the "Imaginary" inputs. Then, after you "run" with that code, your original data will be replaced with the spectrum strength values. Real and Imaginary values may come out but you can get a good idea of the spectrum by again examining the Real values.

Comment: how do i pass event.data.readFloat() to run() as it should be a Vector.<Number> ?

Comment: If you're talking about that FFT2 class.. don't adjust anything there. See my answer on how to implement.